# Laravel how to get User Profile field from separate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and `Eloquent` is quite a challenge for me to understand. I have a User and a UserProfile model and table. UserProfile table has `user_id` (FK to user's id), '`key`, and `value` fields.

I want to get the values of all the UserProfile fields associated with the user_id. Here is my code but nothing works. I am sure I am making some stupid mistakes but still learning :) Laravel.

### UserProfile Model

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'key',
        'value',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

### User Model method

```
public function profileFields(){

    return $this->hasMany(UserProfile::class);

}
```

### UserProfile Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('key', 191);
        $table->longText('value');

        $table->foreign('user_id', 'user_profile_uid_fk')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'key'], 'user_profile_unique_key');
    });
}
```

I am trying to get the profile fields for the user using `User::findOrFail(10)->profileFields` but it is giving me `property not defined` exception.

> **Need Help:** Can anyone help me to make it work so I can get all `user_profiles`
>   fields from the profile table?

### Error Output (Tinker)

> **>>> User::findOrFail(10)->profileFields**
>
> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table 'velvetpaper.user_user_profile'
>   doesn't exist (SQL: select `user_profiles`.*,
>   `user_user_profile`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
>   `user_user_profile`.`user_profile_id` as `pivot_user_profile_id` from
>   `user_profiles` inner join `user_user_profile` on `user_profiles`.`id`
>   = `user_user_profile`.`user_profile_id` where `user_user_profile`.`user_id` = 10)'

Comment: Are you sure that it's failing from that line? Because Eloquent doesn't throw an exception when you try to access an undefined property, it simply returns `null`.

Comment: Can you show us the whole error message?

Comment: I am trying in tinker. Let me post the output

Comment: @ChinLeung I have updated question with output. I realized there is something wrong with relation as it is searching for `user_user_profile` that sounds weired. :S

Comment: Are you sure you've used the `hasMany` relation in your `App\User` model instead of a `belongsToMany`? It would make sense for Laravel to search in `user_user_profile` table if you've used a `belongsToMany`.

Comment: I have used hasMany. Please see the code in question. I have posted for both models. If you need anything more let me know. Also, let me clarify again that I have two tables Users and UserProfile there is no pivot table. I am directly inserting FK userid in user profile table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209084/discussion-between-chin-leung-and-code-lover).

Comment: @ChinLeung it is fixed. I just added FK's argument to both eloquent methods and resolved them. Thanks a lot. I am posting it as an answer and please have a look if iit is a correct way to do or not. your feedback will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between `users` and `user_profiles` is a one to many.

You might have not restarted Tinker since you are getting the wrong error, dont forget to exit Tinker after the modification in the code. Once tinker is started, code changes wont affect it.

Comment: That's not true though. A user will have multiple profile fields. If you look at the database migration, it is one data per record setup.

Comment: This will returns only one item.

Comment: oh, then just restart your tinker console.

Answer (score 0):

you can use join to implement this stuff. like this...
this is query builder

```
$data['profile']=DB::table(usertable)
->where('usertable.id',$id)
->leftjoin('userprofiletable','usertable.id','=','userprofiletable.user_id')
->first();

return view('profile_view',$data)
```

//view

```
$profile->fullname
$profile->sex
$profile->phone
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but I am looking for Eloquent way. Can you help me with that?